# gconftool2 settings aren't saved permanently

Tags: settings, gconf, hamster

I tried to change some settings with the `gconftool-2`:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set "/apps/hamster-indicator/show_label" --type bool "true"
```

Checking if it was set returns true:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get "/apps/hamster-indicator/show_label"
true
```

Now if I logout and login again (to make the changes appear) the settings are discarded and it is set back to false. I also tried it with `sudo`.

Do you know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
gconftool-2 --dump /|grep show_label
```

is there any result?

Comment: Yes there are 3 entries: `<key>/apps/hamster-indicator/show_label</key>`, `<schema_key>/schemas/apps/hamster-indicator/show_label</schema_key>`, `<key>/schemas/apps/hamster-indicator/show_label</key>`. What does this mean?

Comment: the manpage say : "These keys are cached in memory, and saved to disk in XML format when appropriate." I think the key not save in the xml file yet, so when relogin, the key loss!

Comment: Okay thanks syler, this is weird. I guess it would be appropriate for gconf to save it. I am thinking of two options: setting it at startup (meh) or 'hacking' `~/.gconf/apps/.../%gconf.xml` (meh). I don't think both are satisfiable. But thanks for the information

Comment: @DanLee yes! It's weird, I just try it in my ubuntu10.04, there is no this kind of problem. My OS works well!!  "~/.gconf/apps/hamster-indicator/%gconf.xml" exist! when relogin

Comment: Well for now I just put this into startup. Not satisfying but at least it does its job.